# Does the crypto Module on NodeJS support PKCS12?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, pkcs#12

I am trying to use the crypto module to encrypt/decrypt , but the docs do not mention compatibility with PKCS12 (they explicitly mention 1 and 8). Anyone here able to clarify whether support for PKCS12 exists?Thanks